# mod_rewrite to not visible file

Tags: .htaccess

I'm missing something about .htaccess.

working tree like:

```
/
/subdomain
/subdomain/.htaccess
/subdomain/index.php
/assets
/assets/...
```

the htaccess is inside subdomain and I'm accessing this like: `http://subdomain.localhost/`

assets is outside of subdomain and I did this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ http://localhost/assets/$1
```

Now, when subdomain/index.php tries to load something like assets/style.css the rewriterule redirect to `http://localhost/assets/style.css`.

The problem appears when I try to load a javascript file. It's recognized as a different domain, and doesn't work properly.

Is there a way to make `http://subdomain.localhost/assets` works as (and not a redirection) `http://localhost/assets` via some magic rewriterule or something else?

I tried `^assets/(.*)$ ../assets/$1` but it seems not working.

Comment: Please see the [`Alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive.

Comment: in what moment this was PHP related question?

Comment: Answers using php code are accepted.

Comment: @OrlandoLeite: If you accept PHP as answers, please show what you've tried so far in PHP.

Comment: @OrlandoLeite just write one `.htaccess` file and store it in root directory. and rules will be different for `assets/` and `subdomain/`. Also, u cant access parent directories, `.htaccess` loop through only child ones.

Comment: @hakre, Alias works but many online shared server don't accept it. I solved using StasGrin idea. One big .htaccess at root managing access.

Comment: After the end it could be done using only htaccess and you're correct @WebnetMobile.com.

Comment: Yes I normally use Alias for that so I suggested it. It does not work inside `.htaccess`, that is correct. But thought it might be a good quick help. I wonder if it ain't possible to create something similar with location or something.